# Django Forms Updating Record Issues

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error when I try to update a record in Django using a form. I get an error that a record with that number already exists. Below is my model and view. This is really driving me nuts. I though that Django would just update the record instead of trying to write a new record.

```
class Report(models.Model):
    report_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    detected = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    computer_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    cab_date_time = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    collector = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    addresses = models.TextField()
    fault = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    known_malware = models.TextField(default='No')
    collected_files = models.TextField(default='None')
    registry_keys = models.TextField()
    service_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    sample_requested = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
```

And View

```
def reports(request, report_number):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Report, report_number=report_number)
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render(request, 'reports/report.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the Form defination

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from reports.models import Report

class ReportForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        exclude = ('moderator',)
```

Comment: Doesn't your view need some `if request.method == 'POST':` to separate the form returned for GET/POST requests?

Comment: I've added that during my testing but it didn't seem to make a difference when saving. I still kept getting the same record_number already exists instead of updating the record.

Comment: @user2646288 could you add your form logic as well please.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reports(request, report_number):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Report, report_number=report_number)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(force_update=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ReportForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'reports/report.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I changed the view to reflect that but am still getting the same error. Anyone know how to use validate_unique? I can't find an example that I understand.

Comment: @user2646288 the last thing I can recommend is to try and explicitly tell the save method to update by specifying `force_update=True` in the save method. (See my updated solution)